# How to secure a SOAP web service with WSS with CXF

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, ws-security

My application has a SOAP web service implemented using Apache CXF. I'm not using Spring or EJB, it's just a simple web application deployed in an application container (Payara). The web service is configured through `web.xml` and `sun-jaxws.xml` and deployed automatically. It's completely written by source code with annotations (`@WebService`, `@WebMethod`, etc) without any pre-existing WSDL file.

I need to secure it with WS-Security but I can't find how...

The most promising solution is configuring an out interceptor as [this page indicates](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html), but I don't know how to get an instance of `Server` or `Endpoint` of my deployed WS. If I use the `ServerFactoryBean` class, I'm creating a new `Server` object, but will this help me if my WS is deployed by the container?

So, how can I obtain a `org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server`? Other ways of adding security to my WS?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had to build a service yet, only a consumer but you may want to take a look at the Apache CXF examples available on github under the ws_security directory.

[Apache CXF Examples Page](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/sample-projects.html)

[Apache CXF GitHub Examples Repo](https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples)

Comment: Ok, they can help, I'll take a look and post if I can solve my problem or not. Thanks for the links.